# How can I force RedirectMatch not to escape the redirect URL

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-alias

Today I've noticed that `mod_alias`'s `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` directives show a different behavior in how they handle the redirect URL.

A statement like this:

```
Redirect 301 "/foo" "/bar%20baz"
```

will redirect to the literal URL `bar%20baz`, whereas

```
RedirectMatch "/foo" "bar%20baz"
```

will redirect to `bar%2520baz`, as the redirect URL's percent sign is escaped.

My redirect URLs are already escaped. Is there any way I can tell `RedirectMatch` to not escape them any further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand the [manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) you would not need to percent encode the new URL anyway and could use:

```
 Redirect "/foo"  "/bar baz"
 RedirectMatch "regex" "/bar baz"
```

Comment: You are absolutely right and that's what I ended up doing even though it meant unescaping ~1000 redirect URLs. I was just surprised that there's a difference in how `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` treat the redirect URL.

Comment: "as I understand the manual" - the manual does not appear to make any reference to whether the _target_-URL is automatically URL-encoded (%-encoded) or not? In fact, the `Redirect` directive does not appear to URL-encode the target URL before sending the response. Whereas the `RedirectMatch` directive does! Can't see why there should be a difference, considering the manual states that these two directives are "equivalent". `Redirect "/foo" "/bar baz"` (unencoded target URL) only "works" because the **browser** is "fixing" (ie. URL encoding) the URL before making the 2nd request.